# Which is correct: "building 1 and 2" or "buildings 1 and 2"?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, conjunction-reduction

Suppose there are two buildings, numbered 1 and 2. Which of the following is correct?

1. Residents in **building** 1 and 2 ...
2. Residents in **buildings** 1 and 2 ...

And how about

1. **Building** 1 and 2 are ...
2. **Buildings** 1 and 2 are ...

Comment: Similar: [Pluralizing Numbered Items](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/276160)

Comment: @sumelic There may be a confusion here regarding how to apply conjunction reduction. After all, “Building #1 and building #2 are...” is correct, but if you delete the second *building*, the number changes.

Comment: @tchrist: I'm actually confused myself, otherwise I would post an answer. I've never really understood how "conjunction reduction" works and when it is and isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

*Residents in building 1 and 2 ...* refers to residents in one building, supposing that the speaker is pertaining to a building that is named "**1 and 2**".

*Residents in buildings 1 and 2 ...* refers to residents in two buildings, in **building 1 and building 2**.

In order to explain this further, see this example:

*I love my mother and teacher.* - talks about a single being.

*I love my mother and my teacher.* - talks about the mother and the teacher, separately.